# CSS & navbar edits for a Magento noob - ver. 2.2.6

Tags: product, blocks, css, magento2.2.6, header

I need to make a few simple changes to an existing Magento site, and although I have some wordpress experience, my Magento is currently 0.

It's using a theme called **Smartwave Porto**, and the changes are fairly elementary:

- One of the nav links has `4 sub-categories`, and one of these sub categories has an image attached to it, while the others do not. I need to remove this single image.
- On single product view there is a countdown delivery timer element. I need to move this further down the page
- Again on the single product page there is a bullet list of features. I need to style this list a little.
- I need to add a simple style transition when product categories are hovered over

The last 2 are CSS changes, while the first i presume is a `nav/category` change.  I've looked in `catalog>categories` in the `admin panel`, and there is no image attached to the category in question, so it is coming from somewhere else.

Any help hugely appreciated, and if there's a tutorial or other reference that would help, hit me up!

Comment: check from here https://www.portotheme.com/magento2/porto/documentation/#categorypageconfiguration

Comment: Thanks @magefms - really useful doc! I had an issue getting the custom css to work and had to use !important, but got there in the end. I still can't see where the image in the category is coming from so I've just set it to display:none for now.